# Azure Data Factory Environment Set up

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-data-factory

I am setting up an environment for ADF. I have multiple projects and Segments which I need to support. I have noticed that I can only set up one publish branch in ADF.

Should we create ADF for each project?
What is the recommended approach for setting up an environment ?.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ADFs are required if there is complete different project with different data. If you want to work in same project and just need to manage different environment like development, testing and prod; all this can be managed in one ADF.

A developer [`creates a feature branch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#creating-feature-branches) to make a change. They debug their pipeline runs with their most recent changes. For more information on how to debug a pipeline run, see Iterative development and debugging with Azure Data Factory.

After a developer is satisfied with their changes, they create a pull request from their feature branch to the main or collaboration branch to get their changes reviewed by peers.

After a pull request is approved and changes are merged in the main branch, the changes get published to the development factory.

When the team is ready to deploy the changes to a test or UAT (User Acceptance Testing) factory, the team goes to their Azure Pipelines release and deploys the desired version of the development factory to UAT. This deployment takes place as part of an Azure Pipelines task and uses Resource Manager template parameters to apply the appropriate configuration.

After the changes have been verified in the test factory, deploy to the production factory by using the next task of the pipelines release.

Note

**Note:** Only the development factory is associated with a git repository. The test and production factories shouldn't have a git repository associated with them and should only be updated via an Azure DevOps pipeline or via a Resource Management template.